# Nginx returns 403 when serving a file from S3 via x-accel-redirect, using a pre-signed URL

Tags: django, nginx, amazon-s3

I have the following nginx config:

```
upstream upstream_server {
    server localhost:8000;
}
server {
    client_max_body_size 50M;
    error_log /dev/stderr;
    listen 80;
    location ~ ^/document_store/(.*?)/(.*?)/(.*) {
        internal;
        resolver 8.8.8.8 ipv6=off;
        set $download_protocol $1;
        set $download_host $2;
        set $download_path $3;
        set $download_url $download_protocol://$download_host/$download_path;
        proxy_set_header Host $download_host;
        proxy_set_header Authorization '';
        proxy_set_header Cookie '';
        proxy_hide_header Content-Disposition;
        proxy_hide_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin;
        add_header Content-Disposition $upstream_http_content_disposition;
        add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;
        proxy_max_temp_file_size 0;
        proxy_pass $download_url$is_args$args;
      }
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://upstream_server;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}
```

#### Context:

All requests hit the `/` block and are proxied to the django app running on gunicorn behind this server. For some requests, the django app will return a `200`, with an `x-accel-redirect` header of the form: `/document_store/<PROTOCOL>/<PRE-SIGNED S3 URL>`.

#### Expected behaviour:

Nginx intercepts the response with the `x-accel-redirect` header, and instead serves the file from the pre-signed s3 url.

#### Actual behaviour:

Django successfully returns a `200`, with the header set as expected. Nginx intercepts this request, and returns a `403`.

I have logged out the contents of the `x-accel-redirect` header, and passed `<PROTOCOL>://<PRE-SIGNED S3 URL>` to curl, which results in the file being downloaded successfully, so I am confident that:

- The header is being constructed properly
- The pre-signed header gives access to the file in question

Comment: Hey, do you figure this out? I have the same problem.